# Denominator in the Quotient Field of a Projective Coordinate Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $S=k[T_0, \dots, T_n]$, $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety and $k[X] :\mathrel{=} S / I_h(X)$ be the homogenous / projective coordinate ring, which is an integral domain and graded by setting

\begin{align}
k[X]_n := S_n / (S_n \cap I_h(X) ),
\end{align}
and where $S_n$ is the set of homogenous polynomials of $S$ with degree $n$.

In my algebraic geometry lecture, we stated that
$ k_h[X]:=\text{Quot}(k[X]) $
is a graded field and that we have $$ k_h[X] = \{ \frac{g}{h} \mid g,h \in k[X], h \neq 0 \text{ homogenous} \}.  \quad(*) $$

Now I can see that $k_h[X]$ is graded by defining the grade of a fraction to be the difference of the representing numerator and denominator, but I can't really see why (*) should hold, because I don't see why we should be always able to express the denominator as a homogenous polynomial (maybe it is a typo and it was instead meant that this is generating $k_h[X]$). For example, I don't see how we could express for $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ the fraction
$$ \frac{1}{T_0+1} \in \text{Quot}(k[X])=\text{Quot}(k[T_0,T_1]) $$
in such a way. Is this a mistake in my lecture or am I overseeing something? (e.g. we don't take the Quotient field, but instead the ring of fractions over the multiplicative set of homogenous polynomials).

I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

The best sense I can make of (*) is that the left-hand side was supposed to be $k[X]_{h}$, the localization of $k[X]$ at a fixed homogeneous element $h$, and the right-hand side was supposed to be $\{g/h : g \in k[X]\}$, with the conditions $h \in k[X]$ and $h \neq 0$ homogeneous outside of the equation. Regular functions on projective varieties need to be locally ratios of homogeneous elements of the same degree. Thus they live in a subfield of the fraction field of $k[X]$.